# Python TA library, ATR getting errors in dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

my code

```
import ccxt
import ta
import pandas as pd

ftx = ccxt.ftx()
markets = ftx.load_markets()
df = pd.DataFrame(ftx.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, timeframe='1h'))
df.rename(columns = {0:'time', 1:'open', 2:'high', 3:'low', 4:'close', 5:'volume'}, inplace = True)    
df['atr'] = ta.volatility.AverageTrueRange(df.high,df.low,df.close, window=14, fillna=True)
#df.dropna(inplace=True)
df = df[['open','high','low','close','volume','atr']]
print(df)
```

the output i am getting
[image: atr column errors]

any idea what's causing this? (i have tested other technicals such as RSI, and MACD they seems to be working just perfectly with same dataset - Link to this techincal - https://technical-analysis-library-in-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ta.html#ta.volatility.AverageTrueRange)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution can be found in the documentation you linked. The keyword in this case is `class`.

From the documentation:

> `class` ta.volatility.AverageTrueRange (...)
>
> ...
>
> average_true_range() -> pandas.core.series.Series

So you are currently just creating a `class` holding parameters for creating your desired output. However, you are not calling the function (`average_true_range()`) that actually calulates and returns the `Series`you can add to your `DataFrame`.
Therefore, change your code as shown below to add the `atr` series to your `DataFrame`.

```py
import ta
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'high': [10, 10, 10],
    'low': [8, 8, 8],
    'open': [9, 9, 9],
    'close': [9, 9, 9]
})

df['atr'] = ta.volatility.AverageTrueRange(
    df.high,
    df.low,
    df.close,
    window=2,
    fillna=False
).average_true_range() # <- call function


print(df)
```

Comment: I had a same problem. your answer was so useful for me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
atr = df.ta.atr(high= df.high, low=df.low, close=df.close, window = 14, fillna= True)

df['atr'] = df.index.map(atr)
```